# use selectManyButton with elasticSearch on primefaces

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use the component `selectManyButton` for updating the datalist but it doesn't work. When I use `selectOneButton`, it works correctly.

The method I'm using to filter is an ElasticSearch query.

This code works without error:

```
<p:selectOneButton value="#{carEsBean.carEs.carburant}">

<f:selectItem itemLabel="Diesel" itemValue="Diesel" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Essence" itemValue="Essence" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Hybride" itemValue="Hybride" />
<p:ajax event="change" update="selectedCarsList" />
</p:selectOneButton>
<p:dataList value="#{carEsBean.carsQuery}" var="car" type="definition"
id="selectedCarsList" paginator="true" rows="10" >
```

and when I want to use this, it's not working:

```
<p:selectManyButton value="#{carEsBean.carEs.carburant}">

<f:selectItem itemLabel="Diesel" itemValue="Diesel" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Essence" itemValue="Essence" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Hybride" itemValue="Hybride" />
<p:ajax event="change" update="selectedCarsList" />
</p:selectManyButton>
```

The query I'm using is :

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(carEs.getCarburant())) {
    if (query == null) {
        query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("carburant", carEs.getCarburant()));
    } else {
        query = query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("carburant", carEs.getCarburant()));
    }
}
```

I'm using primefaces 6.2, jsf 2.3 on Springboot

Comment: PrimeFaces (or even JSF) does not know **anything** of elasticsearch (nor about springboot). Try splitting down your problem. Create a unittest for the elastic search stuff or see if you can create a pure jsf example (without elastic search) that has 'the same problem'... Cannot be related to both (

Comment: i already make this test and they work correctly when i set one value , but can i set multiple value on the same Atrribut ?I think not, because the last value overwrites the previous ones

Comment: Can you set multiple values in java to a `String`? Or do you use something different then? So effectively your question is purely a PrimeFaces `selectManyButton` one of which the PrimeFaces showcase has a working example.. https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyButton.xhtml

Comment: so for this i dont have to edit my querry ? because they work correctly with selectonebutton

Comment: What exact type is `#{carEsBean.carEs.carburant}`? What does 'is not working' mean?

Comment: That is a pure elasticsearch/java thing. If you can populate an array/list in with the `p:selectManyButton`, JSF and PrimeFaces have done their thing. Whether you need to change the query when switching from a String to an arrayt/list needs query changes is a pure elasticsearch thing. That is narrowing down problems (=approaching this as a developer)

Comment: @Selaron yes my type is #{carEsBean.carEs.carburant} , they not work i mean the datalist was not uploaded

Comment: `#{carEsBean.carEs.carburant` is not a **TYPE** it is a value expression in EL. String, ArrayList, Boolean those are types...  And 'datalist not uploaded' is not a developer analysis.

Comment: @Kukeltje i mean my Atrribut String type  # {carEsBean.carEs.carburant}, and datalist not updated sorry

Comment: How many instances of String can be stored in a property of type String by a select***Many***Button?

Comment: @Selaron in my example,i need to set a 3 values in selectManyButton

Comment: Do you get any error in logfiles?

Comment: @Selaron no the console didn't show a error

Comment: No error? Not even when running in JSF development mode?

Comment: @Kukeltje  yeah this not show a error , the only think changed is the datalist was not updated (but with selectOneButton is updated)

Comment: Then check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value. Most likely validation errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `carEsBean.carEs.carburant` this part should be a list of Strings `List<String>`, not a `String` to be able to use SelectManyButton

Check the showcase for more info
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyButton.xhtml